# Передать массив в edit.blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я хочу передать значение в форму, но по какой-то причине в index.blade я вижу массив, который он заполнен, а для form.blade по какой-то причине массив пуст.

В form.blade я хочу засунуть все уже выбранное значение из массива в iput, а затем обновить информацию
Массив возвращает null в edit.blade

SystemController

```
class SystemController extends Controller{



public function index(){
    return view('admin.options.index',[
        'options' => DB::table('systems')->first(),
    ]);
}


public function edit(System $system){
    return view('admin.options.edit',[
        'array' => $system,

    ]); 
}

public function update(Request $request,System $system){
    $system->update($request->except('id'));
    /*$last_row = DB::table('systems')->latest()->first();*/
    $system->first_column = $request['first_column'];
    $system->second_column = $request['second_column'];
    $system->third_column = $request['third_column'];
    // $system->update($last_row); 
    $system->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.options.index');
}
```

index.blade

```
<tbody>
<?php $array = json_decode(json_encode($options), true); ?>
 <?php var_dump($array) ?>
  <tr>
   < td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
   <td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
   <td>{{$array['first_column'] ?? ""}}</td>
   <td class="text-right">

      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('admin.options.edit', $array)}}"><i class="fa fa- edit"></i></a>

  </td>
</tr>
```

var_dump get

```
 array(4) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["first_column"]=> string(13) "
 dsfdsf

" ["second_column"]=> string(15) "
dsfsfdsf

" ["third_column"]=> string(13) "
dsfdsf

 " }
```

edit.blade.php

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.options.update', $array)}}" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  {{-- Form include --}}

 @include('admin.options.partials.form')
```

form.blade.php

```
<?php $systemm = (object) $system ?>

<div class="rtq">
  <label for="">firsts column</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_column" value="{{ $systemm ?  $systemm->first_column : '' }}">  
</div>
```

У  меня почему то везде в input выводятся 1  1  1  , а не мой контент и я хотел бы сделать update

array в form.blade

```
object(App\System)#310 (26) { ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(12) "first_column" [1]=> string(13) "second_column" [2]=> string(12) "third_column" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(7) "systems" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(9) ["first_column"]=> string(4) "gggg" ["second_column"]=> string(15) "
dsfsfdsf

" ["third_column"]=> string(13) "
dsfdsf

" } ["original":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(9) ["first_column"]=> string(4) "gggg" ["second_column"]=> string(15) "
dsfsfdsf

" ["third_column"]=> string(13) "
dsfdsf

" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а Вы уверенны что в вашем методе

```
public function edit(System $system){
    return view('admin.options.edit',[
        'array' => $system,

    ]); 
}
```

нашло\получил модель `System`?
тут 2 варианта есть, если вы уже передаете из 
`index.blade` массив в виде параметров

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('admin.options.edit', $array)}}"><i class="fa fa- edit"></i></a>
```

то и доставать его надо с помощью `Illuminate\Http\Request`

```
public function edit(Request $request){
    return view('admin.options.edit',[
        'array' => $request->all(),

    ]); 
}
```

н как по мне это приведет к котылю в конечном итоге, а вот если пойти вторым вариантом, и передавать к примеру в `index.blade` ид модели

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('admin.options.edit', ['id' => $array->id])}}"><i class="fa fa- edit"></i></a>
```

потом в методе `edit()` своего контроллера искать модель по айди

```
public function edit(int $id){
    return view('admin.options.edit',[
        'array' => System::find($id),

    ]); 
}
```

и в методое `update()`

```
public function update(int $id, Request $request){
$model = System::find($id);
$model->update([$request->all()]); // в случае когда в моделе обьявленны `$fillable` поля. Если нет, делаете по своему шаблону
...
}
```

Comment: спасибо получилось, но вот другая проблема У меня почему то везде в input выводятся 1 1 1 , а не мой контент и я хотел бы сделать update. Код формы добавил в вопрос, помогите , пожалуйста

Comment: У меня везде выводит 1 1 1 и не хочет обновлять. я попробовал ваш способ

Comment: `<?php $systemm = (object) $system ?>` зачем Вам данная строка? вы в `edit()` передаете модель `'array' => System::find($id)`

Comment: <div class="rtq">
  <label for="">firsts column</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_column" value="{{ $array ?  $array->first_column : '' }}">  
</div>

Comment: всёравно выводит везде 1 1 1 и обновление не происходит. За место 1  1 1 должен быть текст с массива

Comment: тогда просто продебажте какие вы параметры передаете в `edit()` и будете понимать что делать дальше

Comment: `  <?php var_dump($array)  ?> ` и там внутри тот массив , который я писал в вопросе, но в инпут почему то единицы выводятся, не знаю почему

Comment: для начала тебе надо понять что это не массив а Модель класса System, и если тебе нужны какие-то поля данной модели, ты должен к ним обращаться `System->myFieldName`, ну или если ты не хочешь сильно парится и оставить как есть просто в методе `edit()`  измени `'array' => System::find($id)` на `'array' => System::find($id)->toArray()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105871/discussion-between-bohdan-petrenko-and-nikita-kurilovic).

Comment: давайте продолжим в чате